# Unable to access a variable in a function which belongs to other function of same class?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to OOPS.I am creating a GUI with tkinter in python.I am trying to access a variable in a function which belongs to other function in same class.Getting error as 'labels' object has no attribute 'bgcolor'.bgcolor belongs to lbl_property function and i am accessing it in write function.Getting error at line no:85
Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Colsoftware\Python1\Created Python\Tkinter IDE\Page.py", line 138, in write
    self.obj.write(self.dict1)
  File "E:\Colsoftware\Python1\Created Python\Tkinter IDE\label.py", line 85, in write
    string='\n'+j+'='+'Label('+self.title+','+'bg='+self.bgcolor+','+'fg='+self.fgcolor+','+'width='+self.width+','+'height='+self.height+','+'anchor='+self.loc_var1.get()
AttributeError: 'labels' object has no attribute 'bgcolor
```

## Program

```
from tkinter import *
from dnd import *
class labels:
    def __init__(self,root,prop,title):
        self.root=root
        self.prop=prop
        self.counter=1
        self.title=title
    #=========================
    def fcounter(self):
        self.counter+=1
    #-----------------
    def label(self,dict1):
        self.name_var=Label(self.root,text='Label'+str(self.counter))
        self.name_var.pack()
        self.name_var.bind("<Button-2>",self.lbl_property)
        make_draggable(self.name_var)
        if 'label_widget' in dict1.keys():
            dict1['label_widget'].append('label'+str(self.counter))
        else:
            dict1['label_widget']=['label'+str(self.counter)]
        self.fcounter()
        print(dict1)

    def lbl_property(self,event):
        #====================
        self.lbl_variable=Label(self.prop,text="Variable",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_variable.place(x=10,y=10)
        self.lbl_bgcolor=Label(self.prop,text="Background Color",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_bgcolor.place(x=10,y=50)
        self.lbl_fgcolor=Label(self.prop,text="Text Color",font=("",13,""),width=18,anchor="w",bg="white")
        self.lbl_fgcolor.place(x=10,y=90)
        self.lbl_width=Label(self.prop,text="Width",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_width.place(x=10,y=130)
        self.lbl_height=Label(self.prop,text="Height",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_height.place(x=10,y=170)
        self.lbl_anchor=Label(self.prop,text="Anchor",font=("",13,""),anchor="w",width=18,bg="white")
        self.lbl_anchor.place(x=10,y=210)

        #======================
        self.loc_var1=StringVar(self.prop)
        self.loc_var1.set("center")
        self.bgcolor="white"
        self.fgcolor="black"
        self.width=10
        self.height=1
        #==========================
        self.ety_variable=Entry(self.prop,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_variable.place(x=190,y=10)
        self.ety_variable.insert(0,self.name_var)
        self.ety_bgcolor=Entry(self.prop,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_bgcolor.place(x=190,y=50)
        self.ety_fgcolor=Entry(self.prop,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_fgcolor.place(x=190,y=90)
        self.ety_width=Entry(self.prop,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_width.place(x=190,y=130)
        self.ety_height=Entry(self.prop,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.ety_height.place(x=190,y=170)
        self.opt_anchor=OptionMenu(self.prop,self.loc_var1,"center","n","s","w","e","ne","nw","sw","se")
        self.opt_anchor.config(width=24, relief="groove",bg="white",highlightthickness=0)
        self.opt_anchor.place(x=190,y=210)
    #===========
        self.btn_apply=Button(self.prop,text="Apply",command=lambda:self.apply(event), borderwidth=2, relief="groove",width="20",bg="white")
        self.btn_apply.place(x=150,y=650)
    #=================
    def apply(self,event):
        if self.ety_bgcolor.get()!="":
            self.bgcolor=self.ety_bgcolor.get()
        if self.ety_fgcolor.get()!="":
            self.fgcolor=self.ety_fgcolor.get()
        if self.ety_width.get()!="":
            self.width=self.ety_width.get()
        if self.ety_height.get()!="":
            self.height=self.ety_height.get()
        if self.loc_var1.get()!="center":
            self.loc_var1.set(self.loc_var1.get())
        event.widget.configure(bg=self.bgcolor,fg=self.fgcolor,width=self.width,height=self.height,anchor=self.loc_var1.get())

    def write(self,dict1):
        fwrite=open('dummy.py','a')
        for i in dict1.values():
            for j in i:
                self.wname=str(i).replace('.!toplevel.!','')
                print(self.wname)
                string='\n'+j+'='+'Label('+self.title+','+'bg='+self.bgcolor+','+'fg='+self.fgcolor+','+'width='+self.width+','+'height='+self.height+','+'anchor='+self.loc_var1.get()
        fwrite.write(string)
```

Comment: Could you please reduce that to a [mcve], with emphasis on minimal?

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: @wwii.I added my traceback in code section

Comment: ***"AttributeError: 'labels' object has no attribute 'bgcolor"***: That's correct, your `class labels` have no attribute `self.bgcolor`. ***"belongs to `lbl_property`"***: That's not possible, a function does not have **any** attribute.

Comment: Put assignment to `self.bgcolor` into `__init__`. And please rename `string` into something other. Finally: use `",".join` instead of `+","+`

Comment: Then how can i access self.bgcolor from lbl_property function in write function.Please help me.I don't know what wrong did i done in my code

Comment: `self.bgcolor` belongs to `self` (which is instance of `labels`) not to one of the methods of `labels` objects. That's the whole point of OOP - combination of data and functions in single namespace

Answer (score 1):

Your class instance does not have a `bgcolor` attribute when first instantiated because there is no assignment in `__init__`.

```
>>> class Labels:
...     def __init__(self,root,prop,title):
            self.root=root
            self.prop=prop
            self.counter=1
            self.title=title   

>>> l = Labels(1,2,3)
>>> hasattr(l,'bgcolor')
False
>>>
```

The `bgcolor` attribute is *defined* in the lbl_property` method

```
>>> class Labels:
...     def __init__(self,root,prop,title):
            self.root=root
            self.prop=prop
            self.counter=1
            self.title=title
        def lbl_property(self,event):
            self.bgcolor = 5
```

You need to call that method first

```
>>> l = Labels(1,2,3)
>>> l.lbl_property('foo')
>>> hasattr(l,'bgcolor')
True
>>>
```

Or add it to `__init__`

```
>>> class Labels:
...     def __init__(self,root,prop,title):
            self.root=root
            self.prop=prop
            self.counter=1
            self.title=title
            self.bgcolor=None

>>> l = Labels(1,2,3)
>>> hasattr(l,'bgcolor')
True
>>>
```

Comment: Actually it has (or had): `self.bgcolor="white"` in `lbl_property`

Comment: ... yep I'm a slow typist